# Saving items added to a TableView via AddButton?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm totally new in Java and Im just trying out different little things. In the following code, I've set up a ListView into which I'm able to add new items via AddButton.

1. Now I'm wondering how to save those manually added items in my program so that next time Im running the code, not only the default items 1-5 within the code, but also the items I've manually added are shown in my table? I think I need to build some external library in which the manually added items are saved and be loaded every time I run the code again?
2. Also how can I enable marking and deleting multiple items with a single button click on delete?
3. And is there a another more detailed way to wright this code *selectedProducts.forEach(allProducts:: remove);* to see the background of whats happening here?

---

```
public class Main extends Application {     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);                               
    }

    @Override                                                  
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {     

        //BAUSTEINE - Eingabefeld:
        TextField nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setMinWidth(100);
        nameInput.setPromptText("Name");

        TextField priceInput = new TextField();
        priceInput.setMinWidth(100);
        priceInput.setPromptText("Price");

        TextField quantityInput = new TextField();
        quantityInput.setMinWidth(100);
        quantityInput.setPromptText("Quantity");


        //BAUSTEINE - Tabelle:
        TableColumn<Product, String> nameSpalte = new TableColumn<>();          
        nameSpalte.setText("Name");                                             
        nameSpalte.setMinWidth(200);                                            
        nameSpalte.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));     
        TableColumn<Product, Double> priceSpalte = new TableColumn<>();
        priceSpalte.setText("Price");
        priceSpalte.setMinWidth(200);
        priceSpalte.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        TableColumn<Product, String> quantitySpalte = new TableColumn<>();
        quantitySpalte.setText("Quantity");
        quantitySpalte.setMinWidth(200);
        quantitySpalte.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));  

        TableView<Product> tabelle = new TableView<Product>();                  
        tabelle.getColumns().addAll(nameSpalte, priceSpalte, quantitySpalte);   
        tabelle.setItems(getProduct());                                         



        //BAUSTEINE - Buttons:
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {                     
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setName(nameInput.getText());                           
                product.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceInput.getText()));     
                product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantityInput.getText())); 
                tabelle.getItems().addAll(product);                             
                nameInput.clear();                                              
                priceInput.clear();                                             
                quantityInput.clear();                                          
            }
        });

        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");                             
        deleteButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ObservableList<Product> allProducts = tabelle.getItems();       
                ObservableList<Product> selectedProducts = tabelle.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();  
                selectedProducts.forEach(allProducts:: remove);
            }
        });


        //LAYOUT:
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, priceInput, quantityInput, addButton, deleteButton);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(tabelle, hBox);

        //EIGENSCHAFTEN DER SCENE:
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);

        //EIGENSCHAFTEN DER STAGE:
        stage.setScene(scene);

        //PROGRAMMSTART:
        stage.show();   
    }

    public ObservableList<Product> getProduct() {                                   
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();     
        products.add(new Product("Item 1", 859.00, 20));
        products.add(new Product("Item 2", 2.49, 198));
        products.add(new Product("Item 3", 99.00, 74));
        products.add(new Product("Item 4", 19.99, 12));
        products.add(new Product("Item 5", 1.49, 856));
        return products;                                            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is probably too broad a question for this forum. You need to decide
   on how you want the products represented in a persistent format. It
   could be in a flat file, in a text format you define (in which case
   you would just use standard `java.io` classes to read and write
   them), you could use Java serialization (again using standard
   `java.io`; note that this is not very popular these days and, while
   it's easy to get it working, it can be tricky to get it to work
   well). You could use a standard format such as JSON or XML, and use
   a library (e.g. Jackson or Google GSON) to marshal/unmarshal your
   products to this format. Or you could use a relational database and
   JDBC or JPA to read/write to the database. (Once you've decided how you want them represented, try an implementation and post specific questions if you are stuck.)
2. Use `tabelle.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`
3. Your current code is basically equivalent to

   ```
   for (Product p : selectedProducts) {
       allProducts.remove(p);
   }
   ```

   Note that this is a little fragile, because removing an item from the list *may* result in resetting the selected items (depending on the implementation of the selection model, etc), in which case bad things will happen when you try to iterate through a list that is changing. It's probably better to copy the selected items to a new list:

   ```
   List<Product> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>(tabelle.getSelctionModel().getSelectedItems());
   for (Product p : selectedItems) {
       allProducts.remove(p);
   }
   ```

   and note that there's also this:

   ```
   List<Product> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>(tabelle.getSelctionModel().getSelectedItems());
   allProducts.removeAll(selectedItems);
   ```

Comment: hi james, what is the most common or most modern way, Json+Gson library or JDBC? I think for the Json way I do need to understand some javascript, which I didnt learn yet... can I also use SQL for that? Pros/Cons?

Comment: There's no straightforward answer to that. You don't need to know javascript to use JSON: it is just a text format for representing objects (javascript is very good at understanding it, but you don't need javascript). But which you choose depends on your use case: do you want to access the data from outside your application, if so, how; how easy is it to incorporate a database engine into your application, how easy is it to use a third-party library, etc etc.